# Change the font size of the IE11 F12 Developer Tools

Tags: debugging, console, internet-explorer-11

Is there a way to change (enlarge) the font size within the F12 Developer tools of Internet Explorer 11? I know you can view source in a text application but this does not solve other aspects such as the JavaScript console. Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(ctrl +) and (ctrl -) work for me, at least in the debugger window

Comment: This is the answer.

Comment: agree, this is the best solution I've found, good work @Anton!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, I can confirm that there isn't any way to change the font size in F12 dev tools.

Here's hoping it'll be added as a feature in a future version.

Comment: I think this post should be delete, as there is an accepted solutions. thx.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl0, Ctrl+ and ctrl- work for me.

My zoom level wound up off, and very tiny.